# Unable to produce output from span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple form from a coursera MOOC on web development. I am using a RegEx in JS to test for valid input, and an onblur effect to display my test' output. For some odd reason it's not working. Here is the code, I'll explain what it does:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 5 Assignment - Simple Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Week5.js"></script>
</head>
<body> <!--The Five Input Elements here are as follows
           1. Text Box
           2. Text Box
           3. Radio Buttons
           4. Date
           5. Button-->
    <form>
        First Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="testFirstName(); "/><span id="firstNamePrompt">&nbsp;</span><br /><br />
        Last Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" onblur="testLastName(); "/><span id="lastNamePrompt"></span>&nbsp;<br /><br />
        Gender:<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female<br /><br />
        Date and Year of Birth:<br />
        <input type="date" name="dob" /><br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I am creating a simple form and the onblur event is triggered by 2 javascript functions, `testFirstName()` and `testLastName()`. I expect to get output on the same line as the textboxes that state that a condition has been or has not been met.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function testFirstName() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var regCheck = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-] {2,15} $/;

    if (regCheck.test(firstname)) {
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById('firstnamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name Accepted!</strong>";
        return true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name must be between 2-15 characters!</strong>";
        return false;
    }
}

function testLastName() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var regCheck = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-] {2,25} $/;

    if (regCheck.test(firstname)) {
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById('lastnamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name Accepted!</strong>";
        return true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name must be between 2-25 characters!</strong>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a reg. expression that tests that characters can only be A-Z (upper and lowercase), Have a space via the `'s'`, or have an apostrophe or a dash in the name. Those are the only allowed characters based on the regex. I am not sure why I don't see text `"Name Accepted!"` or `"Name must be between x & y characters"`. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to explain. I hope this is not verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element needs to have and `id` in order to be able to target it from `javascript` with `document.getElementById()`.

After adding an `id` to `firstname` and `lastname` everything works fine.

Also your span `ids` have upper case letters, which you didn't mention in your `javascript`.

**Here is the corrected code:** (run the snippet)

```js
function testFirstName() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var regCheck = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,25}$/;

    if (regCheck.test(firstName)) {
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name Accepted!</strong>";
        return true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('firstNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name must be between 2-15 characters!</strong>";
        return false;
    }
}

function testLastName() {
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var regCheck = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,25}$/;

    if (regCheck.test(lastName)) {
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name Accepted!</strong>";
        return true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('lastNamePrompt').innerHTML = "<strong>Name must be between 2-25 characters!</strong>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 5 Assignment - Simple Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Week5.js"></script>
</head>
<body> <!--The Five Input Elements here are as follows
           1. Text Box
           2. Text Box
           3. Radio Buttons
           4. Date
           5. Button-->
    <form>
        First Name:<br />
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onblur="testFirstName(); "/><span id="firstNamePrompt">&nbsp;</span><br /><br />
        Last Name:<br />
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" onblur="testLastName(); "/><span id="lastNamePrompt"></span>&nbsp;<br /><br />
        Gender:<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female<br /><br />
        Date and Year of Birth:<br />
        <input type="date" name="dob" /><br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm it works now, but I guess something is wrong with my regEx. I wonder what it is.

Comment: I noticed that you changed the reg expression, what does your regex mean?

Comment: /w means -> Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]. You can find more of it here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/Regular_Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). But I accidently left it there, I was testing an will now replace it with a better solution.

Comment: @Al-geBra There you go, completely fixed. I used your regex. The problem was that the declaration of the variable `var firstName` had capital letters while `regCheck.test(firstname)` didn't. Peace

Answer (score 2):

In order to use getElementById method, you should provide the id attribute to your inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onblur="testFirstName(); "/>
```

And

```
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" onblur="testLastName(); "/>
```